The most unique numbers that can be left in a game of 90 number bingo
Ok, I am wanting to know how to mathematically work out how many different combinations of remaining numbers there can be in a 90 number game of bingo.
The rules of bingo are thus:
a full sheet is made up of 6 boxes with 15 numbers in each, the numbers 1 - 90 inclusive with no number repeated in each full sheet.
each individual 15 number ticket it is made up of 9 columns and 3 rows.
each column contains as follows:
col 1: 1-9
col 2: 10-19
col 3: 20-29
col 4: 30-39
col 5: 40-49
col 6: 50-59
col 7: 60-69
col 8: 70-79
col 9: 80-90
in each 15 number square, a ticket must have either 1 or 2 numbers in each one of the columns (no ticket will have 0 numbers in a column, or 3. Just 1 or 2)
The rules of bingo involve a random number generator choosing the numbers between 1 and 90 inclusive and the player marking off the numbers until they have marked off all 15 numbers in a single box, and then calling bingo to win that game.
What I am actually wanting to figure out is, with an infinite amount of tickets and combinations, given different combinations of the order that the numbers can be called out, how many individual numbers could tickets be waiting on for a bingo?
2 example tickets: (each * represents a blank square)
bingo tickets example
So, if the following numbers had been drawn:
6, 8, 12, 15, 19, 22, 23, 26, 29, 31, 36, 38, 41, 43, 46, 52, 54, 55, 58, 64, 65, 70, 78, 79, 80, 82
This would leave the first ticket in the linked image waiting for 88 and the second ticket waiting for 86. I am trying to figure out how many different numbers that could be waiting for bingo without a ticket already having a bingo. My initial thought was 11, if all the numbers between 1 - 79 had been called, but I have seen that it is possible to have more than 11 numbers waiting, so I was trying to find out how many and also how to work this out?
I was thinking I could work it out using a computer program or through some mathematical formula, so I was just asking for advice here as I was curious as to the answer. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Do you mean that all possible tickets are in play, or just some sample? ("an infinite amount of tickets and combinations" doesn't make sense to me.)

Sorry. I would say that all tickets would be in play. The infinite tickets and combinations meant all the tickets (or at least not a specific amount) and the combinations referred to the order the bingo numbers from 1 to 90 are called out
